# How can i solve an integral which also has an error function

Tags: integration

I have the following function:
   $\int_{0}^{\infty}u^2(u^2-v)^2*[erfc(\sqrt\frac{v}{2})]^2*[erfc(\sqrt{\frac{u^2-v}{2}})]^2 dv$.

How would one integrate these error functions. For first term ican use by parts.

Comment: what is this integral any way???

Comment: @logo i found it from someone who uses it in computer vision and it is interesting for me but i could not solve it.